# Best way to clear session

Tags: java, web, struts2

On my logout action I want to invalidate/clear the session and I would like to know what is the difference between these three ways to do it and which one is better:

```
-> ActionContext.getContext().getSession().clear();
-> getHttpServletRequest().getSession().invalidate()//servlet api
-> ((org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap) session).invalidate(); //Struts 2 SessionAware interface
```

Also, is there any difference between a struts 2's "action session" object and a servlet http session object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last question first: yes, as the docs indicate.

The `SessionMap` is a thin facade that implements the `Map` interface and allows direct access to some underlying implementations (e.g., `invalidate`).

First question: meh between the last two, the first does something slightly different.

`clear` just removes entries, IIRC it does *not* actually invalidate the session. I'd tend towards `SessionMap.invalidate()` because I try to avoid being tied directly to servlet specs, but I don't see it as a big issue in this case, particularly since it's only likely to be called in a small number of places, e.g., logout.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can please indicate where can I find the docs with information about the differences between an Action's session VS Servlet HttpSession object?

Comment: @DrJorge In their related API docs? E.g., I searched Google for "Struts 2.3 SessionMap API".

Answer (score 3):

`SessionMap#invalidate()` will call `HttpSession#invalidate()` if it is associated with an `HttpSession` and clears the internal map and removes the session association as well, so I'd use that.

The only other difference asside from api independence seems to be that `SessionMap` provides an `entrySet()` method for all session entries. The entries themselves are fetched from the associated `HttpSession`.

`SessionMap#clear()` will just remove all attributes from the associated `HttpSession` and does not invalidate that session.

For more info, have a look at the [SessionMap source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.16.2/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/SessionMap.java/).

Comment: (`entrySet` comes from its `Map` implementation, so unlike `HttpSession` it actually follows `Map`, instead of `setAttribute`/`getAttribute`, allowing for a bit more flexibility.)

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, basically `SessionMap` is just what the name says: a map interface for the session attributes, i.e. it's directly backed by the session :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code for better results

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
```